# Is it possible to disable haptic feedback for UISwitch?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiswitch, haptic-feedback

Having a related issue, so is it possible disable haptic feedback of UISwitch to make it work without haptic vibration like at iPhone6 for instance?

Comment: add the related code

Comment: turning off haptic feedback programmatically is impossible as iOS does not allow it (in my knowledge) but it can be done by the user by visiting the settings https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/turn-off-haptic-feedback-iphone/